# Any alternate TinyMCE4 themes / subthemes?

Tags: theme-development, javascript, tinymce, css, plugin-tinymce

TinyMCE4 in WordPress 3.9 has some cool changes, but it seems to have only one "theme" included.

Is there any way to make a sub-theme of the theme defined by CSS, and `theme.js` in `wp-includes/js/tinymce/themes/modern` ? Or a way to dequeue and enqueue a custom theme from somewhere else? Where can I find these MCE4 themes, if it's a common pluggable option?

I'm also really curious what the `tinymce.ThemeManager.get('modern')` is meant for, since it only gives you the `function(editor) {... }` containing private variables and functions from `theme.js`, but gives you no way to "monkey patch" the reposition or add-toolbar functions, etc. that are within that function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this question is still relevant or not (so I'm posting for future reference for people), but there is a way to define a css file for the TinyMCE editor in your plugin by using the `mce_css` filter. For a quick example, I'll take an excerpt from the WordPress documentation:

```
function plugin_mce_css( $mce_css ) {
    if ( ! empty( $mce_css ) )
        $mce_css .= ',';

    $mce_css .= plugins_url( 'editor.css', __FILE__ );

    return $mce_css;
}
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'plugin_mce_css' );
```

For reference on this filter, you can check out these pages:

[mce_css @ wpseek.com](http://wpseek.com/hook/mce_css/)

[mce_css @ codex.wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_css)

Comment: Also to point out for others that need it, there is also a way to do it in your theme development too using `add_editor_style`, see: http://wpseek.com/add_editor_style/, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style and http://seanbutze.com/apply-your-wordpress-theme-styles-to-the-tinymce-editor/.

Comment: Thanks, but that only lets you add/remove styles loaded into MCE, I meant theme behavior that is defined in the js portion.

Comment: Maybe its worth looking inside an existing plugin that already does something like that, e.g. https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/